# how to initiate printing through android?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm displaying a PDF using webview in android, i.e appending my PDF link to `https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=`. PDF is being displayed on click of button, my requirement is that when that button is clicked, the PDF which is being rendered on `webview`, should be able to print. Initiation of printer should be through `WiFi` preferably. 
I'm kind of struck. Are there any apps which I can initiate through my app? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying Google Cloud Print

http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/